# Proving ${\pi\over 2}=2\tan^{-1}\left({1\over A}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left({1\over B}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, products

Let

$A=2^{2^{-x}}$ and

$B=2^{2^{-x}+1}(1+2^{2^{-1}})(1+2^{2^{-2}})\cdots(1+2^{2^{-x+1}})$

Showing

$x\ge2$
$${\pi\over 2}=2\tan^{-1}\left({1\over A}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left({1\over B}\right)\tag1$$

Expanding $(1)$

Using $$\tan^{-1}\left({1\over A}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left({1\over B}\right)=tan^{-1}\left({A+B\over AB-1}\right)$$

$${\pi\over 2}=\tan^{-1}\left({A^2+2AB-1\over A^2B-2A-B}\right)\tag2$$

We know that $${\pi\over 2}=\lim_{y\to 0}\tan^{-1}\left({1 \over y}\right)$$

So this mean that if we only have to prove $A^2B-2A-B=0$

Am I in the right direction?

Is there another simple method where we can prove (1)?

Comment: Multiply $B$ with $A^2-1$ and $$A^2=2^{2^{-x}+1}$$

Comment: I am not getting your point @labbhattacharjee?

Comment: He means that the expression for $B$ collapses and you have the required $B(A^2-1)=2A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right direction. $A^2 B-2A -B=0$ is equivalent to:
$$ \frac{2A}{B} = (A^2-1) \tag{1}$$
that in our case follow from the identity:
$$ c^{2^n}-1 = \left(c^{2^{n-1}}+1\right)\cdot \left(c^{2^{n-2}}+1\right) \cdot \ldots \cdot\left(c^{2}+1\right)\cdot(c+1)\cdot(c-1).\tag{2} $$